# Is it possible to identify text "live" on screen with python without having to save images?

Tags: python, opencv, text

After looking up online and trying some variations of my own, I wanted to know if we can make a live text identifier that identifies text 'on-screen'.
Now, you may directly say, use open-cv and use similar code down here:

```py
import cv2 
import pytesseract 
  
# Mention the installed location of Tesseract-OCR in your system 
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'System_path_to_tesseract.exe'
  
# Read image from which text needs to be extracted 
img = cv2.imread("sample.jpg") 
  
# Preprocessing the image starts 
  
# Convert the image to gray scale 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
  
# Performing OTSU threshold 
ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU | cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) 
  
# Specify structure shape and kernel size.  
# Kernel size increases or decreases the area  
# of the rectangle to be detected. 
# A smaller value like (10, 10) will detect  
# each word instead of a sentence. 
rect_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (18, 18)) 
  
# Appplying dilation on the threshold image 
dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh1, rect_kernel, iterations = 1) 
  
# Finding contours 
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,  
                                                 cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 
  
# Creating a copy of image 
im2 = img.copy() 
  
# A text file is created and flushed 
file = open("recognized.txt", "w+") 
file.write("") 
file.close() 
  
# Looping through the identified contours 
# Then rectangular part is cropped and passed on 
# to pytesseract for extracting text from it 
# Extracted text is then written into the text file 
for cnt in contours: 
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt) 
      
    # Drawing a rectangle on copied image 
    rect = cv2.rectangle(im2, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2) 
      
    # Cropping the text block for giving input to OCR 
    cropped = im2[y:y + h, x:x + w] 
      
    # Open the file in append mode 
    file = open("recognized.txt", "a") 
      
    # Apply OCR on the cropped image 
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped) 
      
    # Appending the text into file 
    file.write(text) 
    file.write("\n") 
      
    # Close the file 
    file.close
```

(Taken from geeksforgeeks.com, url - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/text-detection-and-extraction-using-opencv-and-ocr/)

Now hold up,
I just need to know if we can detect text live on-screen without having to save pictures.

Take a case where I have a python program and I basically enter a string into it and it should just identify the text on screen and print it out without saving any images.

All I require if it is possible or not.
If possible, please please please give down the code(or just the basic idea).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of methods to grab the screen or region and operate within an array.

After a bit of work, I found mss as best for screen capture and my needs.  It is fast, and on each call allows the region to be specified.  This allow capture from a window that is being relocated on the screen.  Here is an example to capture a region and display with cv2.im_show().  Optionally it can set the region for some named window.

```
import cv2
import numpy

desired_window = None
# desired_window = "RISK"    
if desired_window :
    import pygetwindow

def main_example() :
    if desired_window :
        window = pygetwindow_by_title(desired_window)
        last_window = window.box

    winname = "cv2example"
    cv2.namedWindow(winname)  # Create a named window
    cv2.moveWindow(winname, 50, 50)

    with mss.mss() as sct:
            while True :
                if desired_window :
                    window = pygetwindow_by_title(desired_window)
                    if window.box != last_window :
                        print("window:", window.box)
                        last_window = window.box

                    a,b,c,d = window.box
                    region = (a,b, a+c, b+d)
                else :
                    region = {"top": 40, "left": 800, "width": 400, "height": 400}

                frame = sct.grab(region)
                numpy_img = numpy.array(frame)
                cv2.imshow(winname, numpy_img)   # Display the picture

                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                    break
```